# Issue with adding comment

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am making a node API. I am stuck at adding a comment to a story.

I am able to create a comment but instead of pushing it to a given story, it was trying to create a new instance of story.

```js
Story.findOne(req.params.id, (err, foundstory) => {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).json({msg:err})
        }else{
            let comment = new Comment()
            comment.body = req.body.body
            comment.author = req.body.author
            console.log(foundstory)

            //save comment//
            comment.save((err, comment) => {
                if(err){
                    res.status(500).json({msg:err})
                }else{
                    //pushing comment to comments array (ref) in story
                    foundstory.comments.push(comment)
                    foundstory.save()
                    res.status(200).json({msg:"Comment saved"})
                
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

Story Schema

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import User from './user'
import Comment from './comment'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const ObjectID = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId 

const storySchema = new Schema({
    //subdoc ref from user 
    author: {type: ObjectID, ref: 'User'},
    //subdoc ref from comment
    comments: [{
        type: ObjectID,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }],
    //contents of story//
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    body: {type: String, required: true},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    tags: [{type: String}]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema)
```

Comment Schema

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import User from './user'
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const ObjectID = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId

const commentSchema = new Schema({
    body : {type: String, required: true},
    author: {type: ObjectID, ref: 'User'}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema)
```

I have an array of type  "Comment" in my "Story" schema. My attempt is to push those comment to that array.

Comment: better if you could share your schemas

Comment: what is foundstory?

Comment: foundStory is just what I am calling the story that returns.

Comment: I am adding schemas

Comment: did you get `foundstory` as expected? Because this query `Story.findOne(req.params.id` should be `Story.findById(req.params.id`

Comment: It should work perfectly, please check again. Also, your `StorySchema` is expecting `comments id`, not the whole `comment` object.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code like this:

```
Story.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundstory) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).json({
        msg: err
    });
    else if (!foundStory) res.status(400).json({
        msg: "Story Not Found"
    });
    else {
        let comment = new Comment();
        comment.body = req.body.body;
        comment.author = req.body.author;

        //save comment//
        comment.save(async (err, comment) => {
            if (err) res.status(500).json({
                msg: err
            });
            else {
                foundstory.comments.push(comment._id);
                await foundstory.save();
                res.status(200).json({
                    msg: "Comment saved"
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I've changed the **findOne()** method with **findById()**, also the 'foundstory.**save()**' method is an asynchronous call, so i used async\await to handle it.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Still the same error, and for some reason, findById() doesn't work, that;'s why I am using findOne()

Comment: currently doing async/await but still throws the same error

Comment: you are getting an error or is it just creating a new story??

Comment: It's trying to create a new story but as 'title' and 'body' are required, it throws an error.